# Воспроизведение sine wave в реальном времени

Tags: c++, математика, аудио, procedural-generation

Здравствуйте!

Есть несколько десятков частот, из которых методом аддитивного синтеза волн будет генерироваться результирующая волна.
В каждый момент времени волна может измениться, в связи с изменением значений исходных частот.

1) Как реализовать проигрывание в реальном времени? Чтобы при изменении волны, она продолжала проигрываться уже измененной.
2) Какие инструменты воспроизведения звука можно использовать в C++ (кроссплатформенные), с каким форматом данных лучше работать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Надо сшить ряды Фурье по значениям и максимально - по производным, для этого можно использовать фазы обновляемых сигналов.
2. Для проигрывания в реальном времени нужна буферизация сигнала (при этом небольшая задержка перехода неизбежна).
3. Выходной формат .wav - экономия на хранении не нужна, а портить сигнал не стоит.